# In Kali Yuga, how do devas get havir bhaaga, since yagnas are rarely performed?

Tags: gods, kali-yuga, yajna

In Bhagavad Gita [3.10 & 11](https://asitis.com/3/11.html), Krishna says:

> सहयज्ञाः प्रजाः सृष्ट्वा पुरोवाच प्रजापतिः
>    अनेन प्रसविष्यध्वमेष वोऽस्त्विष्टकामधुक्
>
> देवान्भावयतानेन ते देवा भावयन्तु वः
>    परस्परं भावयन्तः श्रेयः परमवाप्स्यथ
>
> sahayajñāḥ prajāḥ sṛṣṭvā purovāca prajāpatiḥ
>       anena prasaviṣyadhvameṣa vo'stviṣṭakāmadhuk
>
> devānbhāvayatānena te devā bhāvayantu vaḥ
>       parasparaṃ bhāvayantaḥ śreyaḥ paramavāpsyatha

By yagna (sacrifice), devas are pleased, and in turn they please humans.

In Kali Yuga, almost nobody does yagnas, or their frequency is negligible. Even the orthodox brahmanas who attempt them have to deal with lot of impurities of dravya, mantra, bhava. Nitya Agnihotra itself is gone from most households.

So, how do Devas get the ghee + rice havis ? Without that, how can we expect them to give us rains, food, aushadhi etc. ?

Comment: @ram could you add passages that mention that sacrifices will be lesser in the kali yuga.

Comment: Very valid question. In fact even in other Yugas when Asuras gained control the first thing they did was to stop the Vedic Yagnas to weaken their adversaries.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in Gita yajna does not necessarily mean oblations to fire. Sri Krishna says:

> 4.33 O destroyer of enemies, Knowledge considered as a sacrifice is greater than sacrifices offering materials. O son of Prtha, all actions in their totality culminate in Knowledge.

And also

> 10.25 Among the great sages I am Bhrgu; of words I am the single syllable (Om) [Om is the best because it is the name as well as the symbol of Brahman.]. **Among** **Yajnas** **I** **am** **the ritual of Japa** [Japa, muttering prayers-repeating passages from the Vedas, silently repeating names of deities, etc. Rituals often involve killing of animals. But Japa is free from such injury, and hence the best.] of the immovables, the Himalaya.

According to Srimad-Bhagavatam(11/5/32), in the age of kali, God has to be worshipped by "Sankiratana-yajna".

So chanting of Harinaama is the only appropriate and enough jajna for kali-yuga.If "Sarva-yajna-Ishwara" Hari is satisfied, all the gods get automatically satisfied :"Tasmin tushte jagat tushtam priNite priNitam jagat"

Comment: @sv. its swami gambhirananda's translation. Its my typo